# Is the following set compact

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, compactness

Let $S$ be the set $S = \{(e^{-x}\cos (x), e^{-x}\sin(x)) : x\geq 0\} \cup \{(x,0):0\leq x \leq 1\}$.

Is $S$ compact? I know I have to show that if $S$ is closed and bounded, then it is compact. Since the set contains $x=0$ though and $x$ is never less than $0$, is it clearly compact? Or is there something more to show?

Comment: Your $S$ is clearly bounded. I think  $S \subset [-1,1] \times [-1,1]$.

Comment: You need to show it is closed, so start with a sequence.

Comment: @user99219 : What set contains "$x=0$"? Equalities are not elements, and more importantly you wrote two subsets of $\mathbb R^2$ with $x$ variables in them, but $x$ is a real number, not an element of $\mathbb R^2$. I know you meant $(1,0)$, I was just trying to make what you say clearer. +1 for showing progress

Answer (score 2):

The only limit point of the first set $S_1$ but not in $S_1$ is $(0,0)$. Since for any $p=(u,v)\neq (0,0)$ and $p$ is not an element of the first set $S_1$, let $r^2=u^2+v^2$, we can find sufficient large $x$, s.t $e^{-x}<r$. Then we can find a neighborhood of $p$, which doesn't intersect $S_1$. Hence $p$ is not a limit point.

Since $(0,0)$ is included in the second set $S_2=\{(x,0):0\leq x \leq 1\}$ and $S_2$ is closed, the union $S=(S_1 \cup \{(0,0)\}) \cup S_1$ should be closed. And it's bounded since it's contained in the unit square. Hence it's compact.

Comment: The set of limit points of $S_1 = \{ (e^{-x} \cos x, e^{-x} \sin x) \, | \, x \ge 0 \}$ is not $(0,0)$ but rather $S_1 \cup \{(0,0\}$. You were probably talking about points in $\overline S \backslash S$, which as far as I know have no better name as "limit points of $S$ not in $S$". Although the rest of the answer is correct, and the points you are describing are the points to look at, since a set is closed if and only if it contains all its limit points, so you only need to look at those not in $S$.

Comment: @PatrickDaSilva You are right. Thank you Patrick!