# Test whether the follwing sets are compact or NOT?

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find which of the following sets are compact and possibly a valid reason for why so I can better understand the concept.

Here are the following sets I am trying to find:

1) $\{(x,y) \in \mathbb{ R}^2:2x^2-y^2 \leqslant 1\}$.

2) $\{x \in \mathbb{R}^n: 2\leqslant ||x||\leqslant 4\}$.

3) $\{(e^{-x} \cos x,e^{-x} \sin x): x \geqslant 0\} \cup \{(x,0): 0\leqslant x\leqslant 1\}$.

Comment: Do you know that a set in $\mathbb R^n$ is compact if and only if it is closed and bounded?

Comment: Yes I do know that however I do not know how to tell if these are closed and bounded or not :( I am really bad at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A set $E$ is bounded if it is contained in a ball of finite radius.

1) is not bounded, consider $(0,n) \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$.

2) is closed and bounded in $\mathbb{R}^n$, so it's compact.

3) is also closed and bounded, hence compact, see the reason [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/966903/is-the-following-set-compact).